# Using 1 intance of google-app-engine to monitor external service

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I planning to create a NodeJS program, that work 24/7, that ping and make requests to an external server (outside of google cloud) every minute. Just to see that it the external services are are live.

If there is any error it will notify me by SMS & Email.

I don't need any front-end for this app, and no one needs to connect to it. Just simple NodeJS program.

The monitoring and configuration will be by texts files.

**Now the questions:**

- It looks like it will cost me just *$1.64*. It sounds very cheap. Am I missing something?
- It needs to work around the clock, I will request it to start it once, and it need to continue working, (by using setInterval). Is it will be aborted?
- What it is exactly mean buy 1 instance. What an instance can do? Only respond to one request or what?
  [image]

I tried to search in Google: appengine timeout, but didn't found anything that helps.

Answer (score 1):

### Free Quota

If you write your application in Python, PHP, Go or Java it can fit in **free usage quota**:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas

So there will be absolutely no costs to run it on Google App Engine platform.

There are limit of 657,000 UrlFetch API Calls per day (more than 450 calls per minute in 24/7 mode) for free apps. 4GB traffic may also be sufficient for this kind of work.

Keep in mind there is no SMS sending services provided by Google App Engine and you will need to spend additional UrlFetch API calls to use external SMS services.
Email sending is also limited to 100 Emails per day (or 5000 Emails to admin address), so try not so send repeated notifications about same monitored server every minute, or you'll deplete your Email quote in 1.5 hours.

### Scheduled Tasks

There is no way to run single process indefinitely without interruption on App Engine. But you don't have to!

You'll need to encapsulate all the work you're planning to execute in every iteration into single task and then schedule it to run every minute with Cron. See this documentation for Python: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron

It is recommended to have some configuration page where you can set some internal configuration or see monitoring statistics, at least manage flag to temporarily pause tasks execution without redeploying your app.

Comment: Thank you ver much. Some question: 1) Why you say free quota only to Python, go, and Java.  What about NodeJS? In the documentation they not say anything about it. 2. I want/must to write in NodeJS. Can I combine it with other python instance, for the cron?  3. Can I add cron to a nodejs instance?

Comment: What it is exactly mean buy 1 instance. What an instance can do? Only respond to one request or what?

Comment: Your question filed under "google-app-engine" tag. Google App Engine is PaaS solution for hosting specially crafted Python/PHP/Go/Java apps: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/whatisgoogleappengine

This is part of broader Google Cloud Platform, which also allows to run virtual machines with any software:
https://cloud.google.com/products/

Comment: I add a tag. In this page Google talk about app-engine & cloud-platform togetther

Comment: If you absolutely need Node.JS then Google App Engine is not what you need. Try Google Compute Engine (for virtual machines) or Google Container Engine (for deploying Docker containers) instead.

Please note, there is no free quota for this services and cost will be greater than inital $1.64 in your question.

I hope this tutorial will help you getting started with Node.js on Google Cloud Platform - https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/